# Android - Alarm with Wakelock not launching Service from intent

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakelock

I am writing an app and am having a bit of trouble with getting my Alarm BroadcastReceiver from starting a desired intent. The code is as follows:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {

     Log.d("Alarm:","Running WakeLock");

     PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
     wl.acquire();
     WakeMe.wakelock = wl;

     Log.d("Alarm:","Running Intent (Service)");
     Intent i = new Intent(context, serviceCode.class);
     context.startService(i);

 }

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);

     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, i, 0);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     Log.d("Alarm:", "Alarm set to run every 1 minute/s");
 }
```

When SetAlarm() is called the code runs the onReceive() and runs through serviceCode class, it also sets the alarm up and runs the alarm every 1 minute. The problem i am finding is that when the alarm fires and runs the wakelock it is not starting serviceCode and running through. Instead it just ignores the new intent.

Note: The wakelock is released at the end of serviceCode.

Any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RTC_WAKEUP` with a service `PendingIntent`, as you are doing here, is unreliable. Moreover, it would have nothing to do with your `onReceive()` method. You need to use a broadcast `PendingIntent` if you want a `BroadcastReceiver` to get control when the alarm event occurs.

If you want to use a `_WAKEUP` alarm, I strongly suggest that you [use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), rather than hand-rolling your own `WakeLock` logic.

Comment: Thank you for this, i have used your WakefulIntentService and it seems to work well. I did however have to tweak the AlarmReceiver so it also checked if power is connected on boot, i hope this is ok with you.