# AlarmManager is unstable

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakelock

I used AlarmManager to set time and expect to do some work in the future. Almost case it work well without problem. But sometimes (just sometimes), the alarm not fired. It is difficult to reproduce the issue and I still do not know the reason. 
I got this issue on several OS version : 4.4, 5.1, 6.0, 6.1, 7.0.

I already used **WakefulBroadcastReceiver** to start a service with Wakelock, but the issue still happen.

Below is my code to schedule a alarm.

```
 Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("todo_id", myTodo.getId());
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, myTodo.getId(), alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }


public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        LogUtil.debug("onReceive()");
        if (null != intent.getExtras()) {
            int id = intent.getIntExtra("todo_id", -1);
            if (id != -1) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("todo_id", id);
                LogUtil.debug("Receiver receive todo id: "+id );
                startWakefulService(context, myIntent);
            }
        }



    }
}





public class AlarmService extends Service {

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();

   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       LogUtil.debug("Service onStartCommand");

       int id = intent.getIntExtra("todo_id", -1);
       LogUtil.debug("Service receive todo id: " + id);

       // do some stuff here


       AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
       return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Does anyone have the same issue like me ? And what is your solution ? 
Maybe this issue come from Android SDK, they made AlarmManager work unstable.

Comment: Had tried it on 6.0 got the same issue but works well no 7.0

Comment: I think some ids come as -1 for your case

Comment: @Mike, Can you tell me more detail why some ids come as -1 ?

Comment: I had the same problem what I did was manually acquired the `WakeLock ` and released it whenever it was needed.I did not use the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Well I was just telling it from the code you handle such that id != -1 it won't do anything.

Comment: @Mike, got it but i am sure it is not the reason.

Comment: @Newone, did the issue fully fixed when you manually acquire the WakeLock ?

Comment: @CauCuKien Give it a try I'd say

Comment: i had the same issue.. i did the same as @Newone

Comment: @Newone  should I acquire the WakeLock on only the Service or for both Service and Receiver ? I think you should have a answer with some code (not only comment)

Comment: [CommonsWare answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21410844/4706252). Go ahead with the same logic I guess there is some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue , i solved this issue by doing all my logic in AlarmReceiver. I was also starting service in receiver which hold my alarm logic. But once i move my code into alarm receiver it works fine. Mine issue was i wasn't ending my service , it kept on running and causing some issue or might be other reasons but it solved my issue. You should try and let me know if this help.

Comment: I will try and let you know the result later. I feel it is a good idea

Comment: Should I acquire wake lock at AlarmReceiver ?

Comment: I tried to used your way but there are some problems. I need to access something relate to SQLite and invoke a network call, so receiver is not a good choice because it run on UI thread.